# parenthesis matching in python using stack

Tags: python, stack, singly-linked-list

I am trying to use stacks to check parenthesis, but the following code cannot output the right result; after checking it several times, I still cannot find the mistakes; any hint or help is appreciated a lot! thanks!

```
open_list = ["[","{","("] 
close_list = ["]","}",")"] 
def check(mystr):
    stack1 = []
    for i in mystr:
        if i in open_list:
            stack1.append(i)
        elif i in close_list:
            stack1.append(i)
    for i in stack1:
        index1 = open_list.index(i)
        expected_result = close_list[index1]
        if expected_result == stack1[-1]:
            stack1.remove(i)
            stack1.pop(-1)
        else:
            print(i)
            print(stack1, stack1, sep = '\n')
            return 'unbalanced'
    if len(stack1) == 0:
        return 'balanced'
    else:
        print(stack1)
        return 'unbalanced'
```

```
# example
list1 = '{a + [b - (c * [e / f] + g) - h] * i}'

# output
(
['[', '(', '[', ']', ')', ']']
['[', '(', '[', ']', ')', ']']
unbalanced
```

Comment: Watch out--lists aren't stacks. They're only stacks if you don't call functions like `.remove(i)` which traverses the list from the front and removes the first match of the object `i` (_not_ an index, `i` is a string here so the var name might be confusing you). `index(i)` also traverses from the front and is not guaranteed to give you the index you probably expect. Use `enumerate` if you want an index-element pair for each item of the list. Also, don't modify lists when iterating over them, this skips elements.

Comment: You iterate over the list and also change it. Better not to do that. Results in very confusing logic. use `while len(stack1):` instead and keep checking the first and last of the list.

Comment: okay; I have changed for into while; but why I cannot use remove(i) in stack? you mean in  stack, we are only allowed to use index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the list you are iterating will cause to skip elements, in the first iteration of the second loop in the check function you will have `expected_result` == `stack1[-1]`, but in the second iteration `i` is the second value in the list which now that is modified it will be '(' instead of '['.

You can simplify the logic by only adding the open symbols into the stack and every time you find a close symbol you compare to see if the last open saved is it's pair, if not it's unbalanced.

```
def check(mystr):
    stack1 = []
    for i in mystr:
        if i in open_list:
            stack1.append(i)
        elif i in close_list:
            if not stack1 or stack1[-1] != open_list[close_list.index(i)]:
                return 'unbalanced'
            else:
                stack1.pop(-1)
    if len(stack1) == 0:
        return 'balanced'
    else:
        print(stack1)
        return 'unbalanced'
```

Comment: thanks! this is much briefer and clearer!!